# Cannot disable port switching in pulseaudio. Removing module-switch-on-port-available no longer works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pulseaudio

I have a damaged audio jack that keeps connecting for a fraction of a second every few seconds. This causes a faint crackling sound to occur when the output is switched to the headphones and then back.

What worked before was to remove module-switch-on-port-available from /etc/pulse/default.pa. Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04 this no longer works. The module is not loaded when you check pactl, but the output keeps changing.

I tried many things but nothing seems to work. I even disabled the headphones by removing the configuration files in alsa-mixer/paths. Indeed when I plug the headphones they do not work. But the crackling sound is still there when I unplug them. The pulse audio logs keep saying:

```
(   5.867|   3.700) D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Headphone Jack' is now plugged in
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-lineout to status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-21 to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-40 to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-41 to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-50 to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.867|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-51 to availability status no
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-71 to availability status no
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] card.c: Setting card alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 profile output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo to availability status no
(   5.868|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
(   5.888|   0.020) D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Headphone Jack' is now unplugged
(   5.888|   0.000) D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-lineout to status yes
```

Lineout is the output I want to use. Any ideas on how to either stop the switching or disable the headphone port.